# Grails External Config Read Incorrectly on First Load

Tags: grails, configuration

Grails 1.3.7

I have some configuration located in an external config file.  One of the entires looks like this:

```
site.maintenance.mode = false
```

I have a filter which checks for certain config settings for specific URLs.  When I do a run-app or deploy a WAR into Tomcat and do:

```
boolean maintenanceMode = grailsApplication.config.site.maintenance.mode
```

maintenanceMode is coming back true.  If I look at the config object in debug mode, this is what I get:

```
site={maintenance={mode=false, message="<p>Our trail guides are working hard to get the system back on track.</p><p>We're sorry, the account system is down for maintenance at the moment.  We'll get it back online as quickly as we can.  Thanks for your patience.</p>"}}
```

I have a controller that I use to reload this config file dynamically and hitting this controller will fix the issue.  But I'm curious as to why it is incorrect on first runs and why the discrepency in what is getting put in the maintenanceMode variable vs what is actually in the config object.

Comment: Where is "manning" coming from, is site.maintenance.mode nested under that in the config?  I ask because based on the snippet from the config and the debug output, it seems like "grailsApplication.config.site.maintenance.mode" is really what you want to assign to maintenanceMode.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious...  You have done a text search in your IDE for "site.maintenance.mode" to see anyplace where it is being accesssed?  Verified there are not two entries in Config.groovy, no left over code in Bootstrap or anything?

Comment: Yea, I've checked all that.  But thanks for the reminder.  I'm going to create a small example app and see if it happens there as well.  If it does, I'll just submit it as a bug unless I can get an answer between now and then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using a Java properties file or a Groovy file?  If you're using a properties file then I believe Grails will interpret `site.maintenance.mode=false` the same way as `site.maintenance.mode='false'` and since Groovy will interpret:

```
"false".asBoolean() == true
```

then that would explain why you would see that initial true value.

I just ran a simple test locally to verify this behavior.  When I externalize my properties in a file called `test.properties` then `site.maintenance.mode=false` initially gets a boolean value of `true`, when I use a file called `test.groovy` then it interprets the boolean value of `site.maintenance.mode=false` as false.  I believe this is because when you use a Groovy file Grails uses ConfigurationSlurper to process it but when you use a properties file Grails interprets everything as String name/value pairs.

Comment: You figured it out!  I was using a .properties file.  I changed it to .groovy and it works now.  That said, I still find it odd that if I leave it a .properties file, I can reload it using config.merge() passing in a new ConfigSlurper loading that file, and it works correctly.  But I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is to have an external Config.groovy file, for instance: MyConfig.groovy

At the end of the standard grails Config.groovy file, I have the following:

```
def ENV_NAME = "MY_EXTERNAL_CONFIG"
if(!grails.config.locations || !(grails.config.locations instanceof List)) {
    grails.config.locations = []
}
if(System.getenv(ENV_NAME)) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getenv(ENV_NAME)
} else if(System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)
} else {
    println "No external Configs found."
}
```

So now you can have a MyConfig.groovy file anywhere in production environment (for example) and then set an Environment system variable to point to this file (or pass it as parameter to startup.sh), before you start tomcat:

```
MY_EXTERNAL_CONFIG="/home/tomcat/configs/MyConfig.groovy"
export MY_EXTERNAL_CONFIG
```

That's it. Now you have an external MyConfig.groovy file. The properties in it are accessible from your grails app as they were part of the standard Config.groovy

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.*
//... 
ConfigurationHolder.config.foo.bar.hello
```

Comment: You have a good answer on how to setup external configuration files, but this does NOT address the question of why the configuration value is not loaded correctly the first time.